# I can't answer my own question?

Tags: support

I have a few older questions that I've recently discovered answers to, but when I click the "answer" button, I'm not able to answer them. Is there something blocking me from doing so that I'm not aware of?

Two of the questions in question:

[Is there a world generator that can create a Minecraft world that is solid rock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41194/is-there-a-world-generator-that-can-create-a-minecraft-world-that-is-solid-rock)

[Is it possible to use Equivalent Exchange to convert Cobblestone to Wood in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42028/is-it-possible-to-use-equivalent-exchange-to-convert-cobblestone-to-wood-in-mine)

Comment: Which questions?

Comment: Updated my question with the questions in question.

Comment: do you get any message when you click "ask answer?"

Comment: Nope, I get the button 'click' animation but nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

It was a popup blocker in chrome that was killing the javascript popup asking if I'm sure I want to answer my question. =)